# Scripting challenge for noob

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting

So, I've been learning Blender from courses online at Udemy and through Youtube for a while now but I just cannot seem to make any sense of the tutorials on scripting and I have a very specific situation that I think needs a script for animation.  Can anyone give me a hint as to how to begin to undertake this task:

*I have a series of light objects that have a diffuse and emission with a mix shader applied to them in cycles.  There are 40 different materials each with unique names.  I want to be able to run a script that animates the factor between 0 fro the diffuse in OFF and 1 for the emission for ON in a random (ish) cycle.  This is a Burroughs B205 panel in CG for the controls of the Jupiter 2.*

Would something like this even be possible with scripting or am I pursuing a hopeless quest here?  Thanks to all for any clues.

Comment: What do you mean with "0 fro the diffuse in OFF ..." ? And yes your stuff is very likely easy to script

Comment: Sorry, I meant that with the factor on the mix shader at 0 it would cut the emission out and the "light" would be off (so to speak) letting the diffuse grey white show and at 1 the light would appear on with emission at full strength.  I have them set up to do that but manually keying all 40 textures would be way beyond my level of ability which you can tell is low. :)  I don't even know enough about what I want to do to form a good search on it.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Can you attach the .blend?

Comment: Also adding an image like https://www.google.de/search?q=Burroughs+B205+panel+in+CG+for+the+controls+of+the+Jupiter+2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGz6WagubcAhXJ3KQKHV_DBIcQ_AUICigB&biw=2133&bih=993#imgrc=IGIWdyTmlFiHqM: would help people understand your question faster

Comment: I didn't know we could do that.  Thanks for the tip.  That image you linked is exactly what I am trying to get.  I wouldn't feel right sharing the blend file: The model was loaned to me by Al Dinelt as an OBJ file and I am converting it to Blender for making animations with it for myself and learning.  But here are a couple of captures showing the node he created and the model as I have it now.  I added the two nodes circled in red. https://www.dropbox.com/s/miwqmwtpd2ukoc9/InkedNode%20layout%201_LI.jpg?dl=0        https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9ftdz17pi3fpxz/InkedNode%20layout%202_LI.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Start simple, create new .blend project and create a very simple material with a single mix shader on the Default Cube. Get comfortable setting the context to the Default Cube, the material, the Mix Shader and the factor. Then investigate adding keyframes. Blender shows *most* of the Python commands in real time in the hidden view under the menu bar as you interact with Blender. Drag down the menu bar to reveal, works in Windows/Mac/Linux.

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't know that was hiding there.  Should helps get me going, I think.